# getting half JSON when using request module

Tags: node.js, json, express, request

I am sending requet to Payu server for verify payment using request npm module in node js express server. following is code

```
var reqpost = require('request'); //required for verify payment
var key = 'tkhyu';
var vhash = 'eff1fc9fe6b6f5184f407c122a4a0e796ef8085acf960ed67a28679884b5ddcf0fde9f776392c2fca617ce180d432cfa1a7e5ad849ecd2d1f4e029ee70e31a89'
var txnid = 'tx1234'
var command = 'verify_payment'
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  //uri: 'https://test.payu.in/merchant/postservice.php?form=2',
  uri : 'https://info.payu.in/merchant/postservice.php?form=2',//live url
  form: {
    key: key,
    hash: vhash,
    var1: txnid,
    command: command
  },
  headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'// Is set automatically
  }
};
reqpost(options).on('response', function (resp) {
  console.log('STATUS:'+resp.statusCode);
  resp.setEncoding('utf8');
  resp.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('chunk',chunk);
    vdata = JSON.parse(chunk);
    console.log('vdata',vdata);
  });
})
.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
  res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

following reespone i get in console.log

```
chunk {"status":1,"msg":"1 out of 1 Transactions Fetched Successfully","transaction_details":{"FLRC2349909348951":{"mihpayid":"10973572053","request_id":null,"bank_ref_num":null,"amt":"1500.00","transaction_amount":"1500.00","txnid":"FLRC2349909348951","additional_charges":"0.00","productinfo":"Wall Wrap","firstname":"Rahul","bankcode":null,"udf1":null,"udf3":null,"udf4":null,"udf5":null,"field2":null,"field9":"Cancelled by user","error_code":"E1605","addedon":"2020-08-26 1
undefined:1{"status":1,"msg":"1 out of 1 Transactions Fetched Successfully","transaction_details":
{"FLRC2349909348951:
{"mihpayid":"10973572053","request_id":null,"bank_ref_num":null,"amt":"1500.00","transaction_amount":"1500.00","txnid":"FLRC2349909348951","additional_charges":"0.00","productinfo":"Wall Wrap","firstname":"Rahul","bankcode":null,"udf1":null,"udf3":null,"udf4":null,"udf5":null,"field2":null,"field9":"Cancelled by user","error_code":"E1605","addedon":"2020-08-26 1
```

I get error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\LMS\lms_server\routes\eapplication_routes\user_api\frm_fee_lrcapi.js:174:22)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:491:10)
at flow (_stream_readable.js:957:34)
at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:938:3)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

if I print only chunk than chunk is printed two times

```
chunk {"status":1,"msg":"1 out of 1 Transactions Fetched Successfully","transaction_details"
{"FLRC2349909348951":{"mihpayid":"10973572053","request_id":null,"bank_ref_num":null,"amt":"1500.00","transaction_amount":"1500.00","txnid":"FLRC2349909348951","additional_charges":"0.00","productinfo":"Wall Wrap","firstname":"Rahul","bankcode":null,"udf1":null,"udf3":null,"udf4":null,"udf5":null,"field2":null,"field9":"Cancelled by user","error_code":"E1605","addedon":"2020-08-26 1
chunk 6:21:39","payment_source":"payu","card_type":null,"error_Message":"Transaction failed due to customer pressing cancel button.","net_amount_debit":"0.00","disc":"0.00","mode":"-","PG_TYPE":"","card_no":"","udf2":null,"status":"failure","unmappedstatus":"userCancelled","Merchant_UTR":null,"Settled_At":null}}}
```

not getting where i am going wrong

**Edit :**
I have edit my code as follows

```
reqpost(options).on('response', function (resp) {
  console.log('STATUS:'+resp.statusCode);
  resp.setEncoding('utf8');
  var body = [];
  resp.on('data', function (chunk) {
    //console.log('chunk',chunk);
    body.push(chunk);
  }).on('end',()=>{
    // on end of data, perform necessary action
    console.log('body 1',body);
  body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
  console.log('body',body);
  })
})
.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
  res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

In end when i console.log body i get following data

```
body 1 [ '{"status":1,"msg":"1 out of 1 Transactions Fetched Successfully","transaction_details":{"FLRC2349909348951":{"mihpayid":"10973572053","request_id":null,"bank_ref_num":null,"amt":"1500.00","transaction_amount":"1500.00","txnid":"FLRC2349909348951","additional_charges":"0.00","productinfo":"Wall Wrap","firstname":"Rahul","bankcode":null,"udf1":null,"udf3":null,"udf4":null,"udf5":null,"field2":null,"field9":"Cancelled by user","error_code":"E1605","addedon":"2020-08-26 1',
'6:21:39","payment_source":"payu","card_type":null,"error_Message":"Transaction failed due to customer pressing cancel button.","net_amount_debit":"0.00","disc":"0.00","mode":"-","PG_TYPE":"","card_no":"","udf2":null,"status":"failure","unmappedstatus":"userCancelled","Merchant_UTR":null,"Settled_At":null}}}' ]
```

**addedon parameter is seprated by ,**

Comment: request lib is deprecated, build up value in 'data', use `.on('end',` event to send

Answer (score 0):

The [`data` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) is only **some** of the data. You can't just parse half of a JSON string.

Build up a string of all of the chunks you receive from the `data` event and process it in the [`end` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end), when you know you have all the data.

Comment: @sangRam - Questions on SO are not supposed to be moving targets. Editing the question to completely invalidate answers is very much **not** okay here.